# Linq Queryable missing a cast?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to grab data from three tables, however I am getting an error on the final join statement and I am not sure why.

Everything DID work fine when I had a single `select e.Name;` but once I added more variables it started having this error problem.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

```
public ActionResult EmployeeInfo()
        {
        var emp = db.Employees;
    var mov = db.Movies;
    var moveemp = db.MovieEmployees;

    IQueryable<string> query =
    from m in db.Movies

    join me in db.MovieEmployees 
    on m.ID equals me.movieID

    join e in db.Employees
    on me.employeeID equals e.ID



    // this join gives the error
    join r in db.Roles
    on me.roleID equals r.ID

    select new { e.Name, r.RoleType, e.Birthday, m.ID };

    return View(query.Distinct().ToList());
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `query` variable or type `IQueryable<string>`. But your query returns anonymous objects (i.e. it has type of `IQueryable<anonymous_type>`). Of course it's not possible to assign such query to your `query` variable. Create view model type:

```
public class EmployeeInfoViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // RoleType, etc
}
```

Use it as model for your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<EmployeeInfoViewModel>
```

and pass list of this view models to your view (don't forget to use `var` keyword when define query - type of query will be inferred from query definition):

```
var query = ....
            select new { e.Name, r.RoleType, e.Birthday, m.ID };

var model = query.Distinct()
                 .Select(x => new EmployeeInfoViewModel {
                      Name = x.Name,
                      Birthday = x.Birthday,
                      ID = x.ID
                  }).ToList();

return View(model);
```

Comment: How come it worked before then? The view displayed all my names just fine on the View page.. I am just trying to clearly see everything. I see what you are saying, but it hasn't "clicked" yet so to speak. haha thanks thus far!

Comment: @Austin originally your query was of type `IQueryable<string>` because you selected single string value. Now type of query changed, but you are still using same type of `query` variable.

Comment: Oh....can I do list or like an array of strings? I wasn't sure if I should make new variables just for  SQL call, will that replicate data at all?

Comment: @Austin you are selecting four fields. You want to build string from these four fields and still use strings model in your view?

Comment: If you are familiar with the auto-generated templates in Studio Express/Studio that each View can based off of, that is what I would like to do. So I believe a Model for a separate page seems correct o that I can auto-generate some fields, but I do not know if this replicates data or anything.

Comment: @Austin sorry, can't get what you want to do

Comment: Sorry, so... my question is, does making a Model double up on data, or is it just a "link" to help the View organize information? I have a context that contains all 6/7 tables so far, so do I just reference those to a model for this custom page "EmployeeInfo"?

Comment: @Austin view model is a model which is bound to view. You can also use it to generate some CRUDL default view template